# Readding formatted draft.js text from clipboard

Tags: javascript, draftjs

When I'm clicking on the button the text from the clipboard is pasted without style, but keeps the current style inline, but that's not what I need.

My code

```
async function getClipboardContents() {
    try {
      const textFromClipboard = await navigator.clipboard.readText();

      const newContentState = Modifier.replaceText(
        editorState.getCurrentContent(),
        editorState.getSelection(),
        textFromClipboard,
        editorState.getCurrentInlineStyle(),
      );

      const newPushState = Draft.EditorState.push(editorState, newContentState, 'change-block-data');

      handleOnChange(newPushState);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error('error', err);
    }
  }
```

What needs to be done so that the text is inserted with formatting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Text formatting loses after using `clipboard.readText()`. You should use `clipboard.read()` instead. It will return array of [ClipBoardItem](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ClipboardItem).

You can read your initial formatting from this object that way:

```
const [clipboardItem] = await navigator.clipboard.read();
const blob = await clipboardItem.getType('text/html');

// Here's your formmated text
const formattedText = await new Response(blob).text();
```

Comment: Thank's, i don't know that!